# Logic: Help me understand Interpretations (or $Assignements$) + Exercise

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra, satisfiability

I've got an exercise that should help me introduce *Interpratations* / *Assignements* in (propositional) logic.
But sadly I cannot get my head around this concept, and I think I'm missing some basic definitions...

The exercise is the following:

> Find a formula $F$ containing the three atomic formulas $A$, $B$, and $C$ with
> the following property:
>
> - For every assignment $\mathcal A ∶ \{A, B, C\} \to \{0, 1\}$,
>   changing any of the values $\mathcal A(A)$, $\mathcal A(B)$, $\mathcal A(C)$ also changes $\mathcal A(F)$.

What I (*think*, I) understand, is that:

- I need to find a formula (how? any random?),
- Which has three *atomic formulas* (what is exactly an atomic formula? Is it *just* a term in propositional logic?), which are either $\{0, 1\}$ (true or false).
- And that formula should change it's truth-value for ***any*** (??) change of either 3 sub-formulas/atomic formulas

If all that is correct, wouldn't $\mathcal A(F) = A \land B \land C$ with $A = 1, B = 1, C = 1$ be a correct answer?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes; *atomic* formulas are the propositional letters of the language, denoted with $p_1, p_2, \ldots$ or in some simila way, according to the syntactical specifications of the language.

Comment: *Formulas* are either *(i)* atomic ones, or *(ii)* built-up from already existing formulas by way of *conncetives*.

Comment: An *assignment* is a function that maps atoms (or prop letters) into truth values: $\mathcal A : \{ p_i \} \to \{ 0,1 \}$. For every assigment $\mathcal A$, using the truth tables for the conncetives, we can compute the  truth value of any "complex" formula.

Comment: Silly example with a single atom *A* instead of three: the formula $F$ will be $\lnot A$. In this case, whatever the assignment $\mathcal A : \{ A \} \to \{ 0,1 \}$ will be, changing the value of $\mathcal A (A)$ will "swap" the truth value of $\lnot A$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks, but, I'm still not fully grasping some things: 1) When you say "swap", that's only a consequence of $F(A)= \lnot A$ (only from the negation and not the assignment, right?) 2) when writing $\mathcal A : \{A\} \to \{0,1\}$ 0 and 1 are the only valid values for A, true? 3) When you say 'whatever the assignment, it's whatever of these 2 values, also right? (Also, is that $\{0,1\}$ A's domain?)

Comment: 1) Yes; if the formula is $\lnot A$ (where $A$ is an *atom*) and the assignment $\mathcal A$ is such that $\mathcal A(A)=$T we have that the resulting value of $\lnot A$ will be F. Thus, if we change the value of $\mathcal A(A)$ from T to F, the resulting value of $\lnot A$ will "swap" to  T.

Comment: Nothing changes if instead of T and F we use $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Thanks again, but in my case $\mathcal A:\{A,B,C\} \to \{0,1\}$ what does that exactly mean? Do the 3 atoms have the same value initially? Or does it mean they each can have one of those values ?  As in, does assignment imply an initial condition/value? Sorry for the inconvenience ...

Comment: It is the "standard" math symbol for *function* (compare with : $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ for a real-valued function). It means that the function $\mathcal A$ maps the *atoms* belonging to the set $\{ A, B , C \}$ into the values $0$ and $1$ (the *atoms* are the "inputs" and the truth-values are the "outputs"). Of course $\mathcal A$ *assigns* a specific value to each atom: not necessarily the same value to all inputs.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Ohhh! Okay that makes total sense now! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $A \land B \land C$ is not going to work, since if $A = B = C = 0$, then it is false, and changing any one of the values $A$, $B$, or $C$ is not going to change that.

What would work is $A \ XOR \ B \ XOR \ C$, since the generalized $XOR$ is true iff an odd number of its arguments are true.

If you can't use $XOR$, then use the $\leftrightarrow$. That is, $A \leftrightarrow (B \leftrightarrow C)$ will do the job as well.  And if you can't use $\leftrightarrow$ either, but can only use the Boolean connectives $\land$, $\lor$, and $\neg$, then use:

$$(A \land B \land C) \lor (A \land \neg B \land \neg C) \lor (\neg A \land B \land \neg C) \lor (\neg A \land \neg B \land C)$$

(this is equivalent to $A \ XOR \ B \ XOR \ C$)

Comment: Thank you. In that case, would I write it as follow $\mathcal A(F)= A \oplus B \oplus C$? Or only $F = A \oplus B \oplus C$? I'm just struggling to understand what the assignment/interpretation role is...

Comment: @user452306 $A \oplus B \oplus C$ is the *formula*, so that would be $F$.  $\mathcal A$ is the truth assignment that maps atomic propositions into truth-values, and thereby formulas into truth-values as well. So, for example, with this $F$, if $\mathcal A(A)=1, \mathcal A(B)=0, \mathcal A(C)=1$, then $\mathcal A(F)=0$. Change any one truth-assignment, and the truth-assignment for $F$ changes as well. For example, if we keep $\mathcal A(A)=1, \mathcal A(B)=0$ but make $\mathcal A(C)=0$, then $\mathcal A(F)=1$